# gnuplot hypertext doesn't work on svg terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file 'test.data' having the following data:

```
0 0 "no yes"

1 3 "yes no"

4 6 "th"

7 9 "fo"
```

I can run gnuplot command from linux:

`plot 'test.data' using 1:2:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7`

It works with the mouse over showing the hypertext from 3rd column. But when I use svg as term, the hypertext doesn't show.

```
set term svg mouse jsdir "http://.../TEST/"

set output "test.svg"

plot 'test.data' using 1:2:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7
```

The I load `http://.../TEST/test.svg`
It plots the data but no hypertext.  Please help! Thanks!

(I also tried adding, set label at 4,6 "th" hypertext point pt 1)

Comment: It is not necessary to add *Please help!* to your title. It's clear you need help or you wouldn't be posting here, so adding that is nothing but useless noise.

Comment: Does the URL directory you gave it contain the javascript support components? 
  I.e. some version of gnuplot_svg.js? I suggest opening it in a browser like Chrome where you can enable the debugging console to see what errors are generated.

Comment: Yes. I have the gnuplot_svg.js. I can click a data point to link to another page, that part works.

Comment: It's working now. I was working on this project several years ago, it looks like the gnuplot_svg.js didn't support hypertext at that time, so there's no showHypertext in it. Now I copied the new version of js. Thanks Ethan for reminding me of checking the js file. I thought I didn't do the "set ... plot" part right, so I spent a couple of days on that, tried everything I could find online. Thanks!